# Using DAO in Access 2007 to connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007, dao

I have an Access 2003 front-end app which uses DAO to connect to a SQL Server 2008 database. I just upgraded to Access 2007 where DAO workspaces are no longer supported. However I cannot figure out how to change the DAO workspace feature in making a connection to the SQL Server 2008 database.

This should be so simple but I can't progress ahead to solve some of the other compatibility issues I know that I'm going to have if I can't even make a basic DAO connection. I worry about converting to ADO because that requires too many change.

I am looking for sample code with the specific names of DAO connection properties. I'm getting an error message stating that it cannot find the database.

**Sample code used in ACCESS 2003:**

```
dim Global_ODBC_WrkSpace As Workspace  
dim Global_ODBC_Conn As Connection  
dim gstrAIScs as string

gstrAIScs = "ODBC;DATABASE=temp;UID=myuid;PWD=mypwd;DSN=PRODSQL"   
Set Global_ODBC_WrkSpace = CreateWorkspace("", CurrentUser, "", dbUseODBC)  
Set Global_ODBC_Conn = Global_ODBC_WrkSpace.OpenConnection("", dbDriverNoPrompt, False, gstrAIScs)
```

I cannot use the workspace reference up above in Access 2007 (DAO 3.6) because it is no longer supported.  Unfortunately the connection object is use throughout the client app to open record sets.  If I convert to ADO there will be way too many changes that I care to make.

Comment: Access 2007 certainly does support DAO. Please edit your question to show us some relevant code and the *exact* error message(s) that you are receiving.

Comment: Also, which DAO reference are you using? It changed in 2007.

Comment: I added a bit of sample code of what worked in ACCESS 2003